# how to launch wso2 micro-integrator 7.0.1?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I can't launch wso2 micro-integrator 7.0.1. I launch files micro-integrator.sh or launcher_micro-integrator.sh or command wso2mi, after that i have strings in logs (look below), after that nothing, MI isn't loaded later. What is wrong? My Java_Home is correct. User who launches MI has all permissions on MI directory.

```
INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8290
INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener} - MAILTO listener started
INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8253
INFO {org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.StartupFinalizer} - WSO2 Micro Integrator started in 4 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the below log, your Micro integrator has started successfully.

```
INFO {org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.StartupFinalizer} - WSO2 Micro Integrator started in 4 seconds
```

Micro integrator is starting in a very little time compared to the WSO2 Enterprise integrator and does not have the Mgt console capability of WSO2 Enterprise Integrator. However, you can access MI monitoring dashboard by referring to this [doc](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/administer-and-observe/working-with-monitoring-dashboard/).

Please check this [quick start guide](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/overview/quick-start-guide/) for more details on WSO2 Micro integrator.

Comment: This whole documentation will guide you. Please try out tutorials set.
https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/overview/introduction/

Comment: Thanks, but how can i open web-console for EI 7.0.1? I tried to open an old web link https://ei.com:9443/carbon or https://ei.com:8253/, no web pages on it. Should i launch ballerina or streaming integrator for it?

Comment: WSO2 micro integrator comes with Micro Integrator Dashboard which is different from the EI Mgt console. You can follow this doc, https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/administer-and-observe/working-with-monitoring-dashboard/ on how to use it

Comment: I launched MI on port 9164, added my certificate and CA-certificate to keystore.jks, changed hostname, but now i have warnings in logs: `WARN {org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.internal.http.api. InternalAPIDispatcher} - No Internal API found to dispatch the message
WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown`

Comment: At what point you got this error? Could you access the MI Dashboard?

Comment: when i open MI in browser, i get this errors. No, i cant access MI dashboard

Comment: You should execute all the steps listed here https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/administer-and-observe/working-with-monitoring-dashboard/

Comment: I opened web page 127.0.0.1:9743/dashboard/login, it works. I tried to open 127.0.0.1:9164, it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually 9164 is the port which runs the MI Management API. But you should access the Monitoring Dashboard which running in 9743. This dashboard is using MI Mgt API. Does this help you to clear your confision?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203747/discussion-between-pramodya-mendis-and-epic555).